# Unable to initialize variables according to Device Size

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error message:  The non-nullable variable 'mediaQueryData' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression
I know it is because of Dart null safety. What I'm unsure about is what do I initialize the values with.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;

  return (inputHeight / 896.0) * screenHeight;
}

double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;

  return (inputWidth / 414.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

Calling the init() function like this.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mediaQueryData` field is `static`, which means it belongs to *the class itself*, not a particular instance of the class, e.g.:

```
class Example {
  static void foo() { ... }
  void bar() { ... }
}

final example = Example();

Example.foo();  // works
example.foo();  // error

Example.bar();  // error
example.bar();  // works
```

Because `mediaQueryData` is non-nullable, you need to provide it an initializer, or mark it as `late`. If you mark it as late, you need to also make `init()` static so you can call it on the class itself:

```
class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData mediaQueryData;
  // other fields

  static void init(BuildContext context) {
    // initialize
  }
}
```

Then in your `HomeScreen.build()`, you can use:

```
SizeConfig.init(context);
SizeConfig.mediaQueryData;  // works now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword late in the variable declaration in order to let dart know this value is currently null but im going to initialize it for sure in the future.

Example from the docs:

```
// Using null safety:
class Coffee {
  // No compilation error anymore becuase now Dart knows it's for sure going to be initialized
  late String _temperature;

  void heat() { _temperature = 'hot'; }
  void chill() { _temperature = 'iced'; }

  String serve() => _temperature + ' coffee';
}
```

You can read more about it here:
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables

Comment: I tried. Doing this is followed by the following Error on successfully building the app
`The following LateError was thrown building HomeScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#e0246], _InheritedTheme, MediaQuery]):
LateInitializationError: Field 'screenWidth' has not been initialized.`